# CustomSession: can I get a RemoteMediaClient from CastSession or is this always null?

Tags: android, google-cast

I implemented a CustomSession and CustomSessionProvider.

onSessionStarted in SessionManagerListener is called with a CastSession != null but the RemoteMediaClient == null;

Is the RemoteMediaClient always null? Do I need to initialize it?

```
 public class CastSessionManagerListener implements  SessionManagerListener<CastSession> {
     @Override
     public void onSessionStarted(CastSession castSession, String s) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onSessionStarted() called with: castSession = [" + castSession + "], s = [" + s + "]");
          if (!MediaRouter.getInstance(context).getSelectedRoute().isDefault()) {
              Log.e(TAG, "SESSION STARTED WITH: " + castSession.getRemoteMediaClient());
          }

      }
  }
```